# Issue with accessing Jenkins api with Vue/Axios call

Tags: vue.js, jenkins, jenkins-api

I tried making a get call with axios from my Vue js codebase/ environment to Jenkins API and I'm unable to do so.

I've read every resource that I could but wasn't able to fix this particular problem. I even created a .htaccess file to see if it help but wasn't useful.I ran out of options so I came here for help.

Below are the axios codes that I used within my App.vue file.

```js
axios.get(
    *URL to access Jenkins that is currently running on a tomcat server*,
    {
        headers: {
            "jenkins-crumb": "* Some numbers and letters*",
        },
        auth: {
            username: "*obvious username*",
            password: "*obvious password*"
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        crossdomain: true
    }
)
.then(response => (this.info= response)).catch(error => (console.log(error)));
```

Console log output:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Network output:

> General
>   Request URL: URL
>   Request Method: OPTIONS
>   Status Code: 403
>   Remote Address: localhost:8080
>   Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
>
> Request Headers
>   Provisional headers are shown
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,jenkins-crumb
>   Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>   Origin: http://localhost:8080
>   Referer: http://localhost:8080/
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36

Please help!

Comment: Seems like a CORS issue. You need to enable CORS on your Jenkins API.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cors+Filter+Plugin